# Vim bind some hotkeys different to filetype

Tags: vim, autocomplete, file-type

I want to bind something like this:

- For CSS, HTML files: `<c-space> <c-x><c-n>`
- For Ruby files: `<c-space> <c-x><c-u>`

How to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html) is more complete, precise and correct, but briefly:

Make a file in your ftplugin folder (create this folder if necessary) starting with the filetype you'd like to use.

```
├── vim
│   ├── after
│   ├── autoload
│   ├── bundle
│   ├── ftplugin
│   │   ├── python.vim
│   │   ├── rnoweb.vim
│   │   └── tex.vim
│   └── syntax
```

and in one of of these files, the python.vim one for example, a line like

```
noremap! <buffer> <F5> <Esc>:w<CR>:!python % <CR>
```

will be a bind only defined for this filetype, just in this buffer.  Make sure `filetype plugin on` or similar appears in your vimrc.

Edit:  excellent suggestions by Peter Rincker incorporated: noremap version of map command and `<buffer>` flag.  He also reminds us to use `setlocal` instead of `set` in our filetype plugin files.

Comment: You will want to use the `<buffer>` flag to make mappings are local the buffer. e.g. `inoremap <buffer> <c-space> <c-x><c-o>`. You will also want to take care to use `setlocal` for options.

Answer (score 4):

Use autocmd:

```
autocmd filetype css inoremap <buffer> <c-space> <c-x><c-n>  
autocmd filetype html inoremap <buffer> <c-space> <c-x><c-n>
autocmd filetype ruby inoremap <buffer> <c-space> <c-x><c-u>
```

Comment: you could also combine lines, `autocmd filetype css,html setlocal...`

Comment: You must remove `setlocal`

Answer (score 3):

Put the following in your .vimrc. Substitute the do stuff lines with your bindings.

```
:if match(@%, ".css") >=0 
: do css stuff
:endif

:if match(@%, ".rb") >=0 
: do ruby stuff
:endif
```